# No visible interface for "UIView" declares the selector "setDate:Animated";

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can you please help me find outwhat am I doing wrong here ? The error on line

```
[self.datePicker setDate:now animated:NO];
```

says

> No visible interface for "UIView" declares the selector "setDate:Animated";

and on line

```
NSDate *selected = [self.datePicker date];
```

says

> No visible interface for "UIView" declares the selector "date";

```
#import "BIDDatePickerViewController.h"

@interface BIDDatePickerViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *datePicker;

@end

@implementation BIDDatePickerViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    [self.datePicker setDate:now animated:NO];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSDate *selected = [self.datePicker date];
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"The date and time you selected is %@", selected];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Date and time selected"
                                                    message: message
                                                   delegate: nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle: @"That's so true!"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];

}

@end
```

UPD

tried change UIView to UIDatePicker and now it builds but crashes with

```
2015-04-08 22:37:26.211 Pckers[3317:211755] -[UIView setDate:animated:]:    
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faa32f26b90
2015-04-08 22:37:26.215 Pckers[3317:211755] *** Terminating app due to      
uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView             
setDate:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faa32f26b90'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: Change your `datePicker` property to `UIDatePicker` instead of `UIView`.

Comment: now it crashes with ' 2015-04-08 22:33:36.440 Pckers[3231:207204] -[UIView setDate:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fda82f560b0
2015-04-08 22:33:36.448 Pckers[3231:207204] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setDate:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fda82f560b0' '

Comment: Are you actually assigning a `UIDatePicker` to your `datePicker` outlet? Sounds like you have assigned a plain old `UIView` instead.

Comment: Rechecked, reconnected and it helped. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have to change it into `UIDatePicker` my advise is to remove the current one from storyboard and reinsert it again as a `UIDatePicker` because most probably you declared it as a `UIView`

something else try to weak reference all your `IBOutlets` as no need for extra retain count here